# WebRTC for Android : VideoRendererGUI take a screenshot in the video call

Tags: android, webrtc, screenshot

The demand is that saving a video frame in the video call. I have made a demo that take a screenshot through the GLSurfaceView's method "onDrawFrame". But when I use the webrtc, it have its own renderer "VideoRendererGUI" .And then when I want to override it, I find it can't be overrided. the main part code :

```
   vsv = (GLSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.glviewchild_call);
    vsv.setPreserveEGLContextOnPause(true);
    vsv.setKeepScreenOn(true);

    VideoRendererGui.setView(vsv, new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            init();
        }
    });
```

And If you have another way to take a screenshot, you can also share with me.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a SurfaceViewRenderer to display the stream, you can use the solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50415439/webrtc-capture-screen/51061090#51061090) to capture a frame on the call.

Basically, using `surfaceViewRenderer.AddFrameListener` with a class that implements `EGLRenderer.FrameListener`

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that the SurfaceViewRenderer of the peer you want to take a screenshot of is called **remotePeerSurfaceViewRenderer**, also I will asume that the button that you will use to take a screenshot is called **btnScreenshot**

So all what you need to do is as "Webo80" said in the answer above use the FrameListener, the issue is the FrameListener implementation of the webrtc takes only the first frame available once the Listener is attached to the SurfaceViewRenderer, so my approach to do that is by attaching the webrtc implementation of the FrameListsner at the second I need to take a screenshot and remove it once it is taken:

```
btnScreenshot.setOnClickListener((view)-> {
    remotePeerSurfaceViewRenderer.addFrameListsner(new EglRenderer.FrameListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFrame(Bitmap bitmap) {
                runOnUiThread(() -> {
                    /*
                    do what ever you want with the bitmap for example
                    imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    */
                    localVideoView.removeFrameListener(this);
                });
            }
        }, 1);
})
```

Important note:

```
1. Please don't forget to runOnUiThread as Iam doing
2. Please don't forget to remove the listener inside the button onClick() method
```

I have tried this solution and it is working more than fine, if you want to make your custom solution you have to completely implement the interface **"EglRenderer.FrameListener"**

Comment: This seems to work. Thanks. But I have a different requirement. I assumed that if I don't use removeFrameListener() the onFrame() would get called repeatedly. But that's not true I suppose. I want it to be called repeatedly so that I can analyze each frame. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry to say due to unavailability of canvas and other facilities in Android It's not possible to capture screenshot programatically using WebRTC. One can dodge this situation by animating the app's UI and capturing the screenshot manually , store it at configured location and exchange it with other party.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav! Can I use the ffmpeg to solve this? Because now I have used the app's UI "GLSurfaceView" ,but it doesn't work.

Comment: I hava found another solution! Firstly through webrtc ,I can get the I420frame in the method 'RenderFrame'. Then I convert the I420frame to YuvImage. Finally,I use the YuvImage's method 'compressToJpeg' to convert it to jpeg image.