# WebRTC, Capture Screen

Tags: java, android, webrtc

my current problem is, that I want to find a way to capture a frame/screenshot during a webrtc connection on Android. I know there are already some solutions to this here but none were working for me.

With my current approach I followed this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/EricDavies/860c9a73d53649f7399e2a4a02fcb9da).

The problem is that it returns a black bitmap. I will append my approach but it basically is the same as the Gist. If anybody has any ideas how to solve this, thanks in advance.

```
Activity SingleFrameCapturer.BitmapListener gotFrameListener = new 
    SingleFrameCapturer.BitmapListener() {

    @Override
    public void gotBitmap(Bitmap theBitmap) {
        Log.e(TAG, "got bitmap!");

        ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.object_preview);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(theBitmap);

        imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        };

        MediaStream stream = contextManager.getStream();
        SingleFrameCapturer.toBitmap(this, stream, gotFrameListener);
    }
}
```

SingleFrameCapturer

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

import org.webrtc.VideoTrack;
import org.webrtc.MediaStream;
import org.webrtc.EglBase;
import org.webrtc.RendererCommon;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGL10;
import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLDisplay;

public class SingleFrameCapturer {

    public interface BitmapListener {
        public void gotBitmap(Bitmap theBitmap);
    }

    private static boolean firstTimeOnly = true;


    // the below pixelBuffer code is based on from
    // https://github.com/CyberAgent/android-gpuimage/blob/master/library/src/jp/co/cyberagent/android/gpuimage/PixelBuffer.java
    //
    class PixelBuffer implements org.webrtc.VideoRenderer.Callbacks {
        final static String TAG = "PixelBuffer";
        final static boolean LIST_CONFIGS = false;

        int mWidth, mHeight;
        EGL10 mEGL;
        EGLDisplay mEGLDisplay;
        boolean gotFrame = false;
        String mThreadOwner;
        BitmapListener listener;
        android.app.Activity activity;


        public PixelBuffer(android.app.Activity activity, BitmapListener listener) {
            this.listener = listener;
            this.activity = activity;
        }


        private static final String VERTEX_SHADER_STRING =
                "varying vec2 interp_tc;\n"
                        + "attribute vec4 in_pos;\n"
                        + "attribute vec4 in_tc;\n"
                        + "\n"
                        + "uniform mat4 texMatrix;\n"
                        + "\n"
                        + "void main() {\n"
                        + "    gl_Position = in_pos;\n"
                        + "    interp_tc = (texMatrix * in_tc).xy;\n"
                        + "}\n";


        @Override
        public void renderFrame(final org.webrtc.VideoRenderer.I420Frame i420Frame) {
            Log.d(TAG, "entered renderFrame");
            //
            // we only want to grab a single frame but our method may get called
            // a few times before we're done.
            //
            if (gotFrame || i420Frame.width == 0 || i420Frame.height == 0) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Already got frame so taking honourable exit");
                org.webrtc.VideoRenderer.renderFrameDone(i420Frame);
                return;
            }
            activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    int width = i420Frame.width;
                    int height = i420Frame.height;
                    Log.d(TAG, "about to call initWithSize");
                    initWithSize(width, height);
                    Bitmap bitmap = toBitmap(i420Frame);
                    org.webrtc.VideoRenderer.renderFrameDone(i420Frame);
                    gotFrame = true;
                    listener.gotBitmap(bitmap);
                    destroy();
                }
            });
        }

        private int buildARGB(int r, int g, int b) {
            return (0xff << 24) |(r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;
        }

        private Bitmap toBitmap(org.webrtc.VideoRenderer.I420Frame frame) {

            if (frame.yuvFrame) {

                //EglBase eglBase = EglBase.create();
                EglBase eglBase = StreamActivity.rootEglBase;

                if(firstTimeOnly) {
                    eglBase.createDummyPbufferSurface();
                    firstTimeOnly = false;
                }
                eglBase.makeCurrent();
                TextureToRGB textureToRGB = new TextureToRGB();
                int numPixels = mWidth *mHeight;
                final int bytesPerPixel = 4;
                ByteBuffer framebuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(numPixels*bytesPerPixel);

                final float frameAspectRatio = (float) frame.rotatedWidth() / (float) frame.rotatedHeight();

                final float[] rotatedSamplingMatrix =
                        RendererCommon.rotateTextureMatrix(frame.samplingMatrix, frame.rotationDegree);
                final float[] layoutMatrix = RendererCommon.getLayoutMatrix(
                        false, frameAspectRatio, (float) mWidth / mHeight);
                final float[] texMatrix = RendererCommon.multiplyMatrices(rotatedSamplingMatrix, layoutMatrix);

                textureToRGB.convert(framebuffer, mWidth, mHeight, frame.textureId, texMatrix);

                byte [] frameBytes = framebuffer.array();
                int [] dataARGB = new int[numPixels];
                for(int i = 0, j = 0; j < numPixels; i+=bytesPerPixel, j++) {
                    //
                    // data order in frameBytes is red, green, blue, alpha, red, green, ....
                    //
                    dataARGB[j] = buildARGB(frameBytes[i] & 0xff,frameBytes[i+1] &0xff,frameBytes[i+2] &0xff);
                }

                Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(dataARGB, mWidth, mHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                return bitmap;
            }
            else {
                return null;
            }
        }

        private void initWithSize(final int width, final int height) {
            mWidth = width;
            mHeight = height;

            // Record thread owner of OpenGL context
            mThreadOwner = Thread.currentThread().getName();
        }


        public void destroy() {
        }


        private int getConfigAttrib(final EGLConfig config, final int attribute) {
            int[] value = new int[1];
            return mEGL.eglGetConfigAttrib(mEGLDisplay, config,
                    attribute, value) ? value[0] : 0;
        }
    }


    final private static String TAG = "SingleFrameCapturer";
    org.webrtc.VideoRenderer renderer;

    private  SingleFrameCapturer(final android.app.Activity activity, MediaStream mediaStream, final BitmapListener gotFrameListener) {
        if( mediaStream.videoTracks.size() == 0) {
            Log.e(TAG, "No video track to capture from");
            return;
        }

        final VideoTrack videoTrack = mediaStream.videoTracks.get(0);
        final PixelBuffer vg = new PixelBuffer(activity, new BitmapListener() {

            @Override
            public void gotBitmap(final Bitmap bitmap) {
                activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                    public void run() {
                        videoTrack.removeRenderer(renderer);
                        try {
                            gotFrameListener.gotBitmap(bitmap);
                        } catch( Exception e1) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Exception in gotBitmap callback:" + e1.getMessage());
                            e1.printStackTrace(System.err);
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        });
        renderer = new org.webrtc.VideoRenderer(vg);
        videoTrack.addRenderer(renderer);
    }

    /**
     * This constructor builds an object which captures a frame from mediastream to a Bitmap.
     * @param mediaStream The input media mediaStream.
     * @param gotFrameListener A callback which will receive the Bitmap.
     */
    public static void toBitmap(android.app.Activity activity, MediaStream mediaStream, final BitmapListener gotFrameListener) {
        new SingleFrameCapturer(activity, mediaStream, gotFrameListener);
    }

    /**
     * This method captures a frame from the supplied media stream to a jpeg file written to the supplied outputStream.
     * @param mediaStream  the source media stream
     * @param quality the quality of the jpeq 0 to 100.
     * @param outputStream the output stream the jpeg file will be written to.
     * @param done a runnable that will be invoked when the outputstream has been written to.
     * @return The frame capturer. You should keep a reference to the frameCapturer until the done object is invoked.
     */
    public static void toOutputStream(android.app.Activity activity, MediaStream mediaStream, final int quality, final java.io.OutputStream outputStream, final Runnable done) {
        BitmapListener gotFrameListener = new BitmapListener() {

            @Override
            public void gotBitmap(Bitmap theBitmap) {
                theBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, outputStream);
                try {
                    done.run();
                } catch( Exception e1) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Exception in toOutputStream done callback:" + e1.getMessage());
                    e1.printStackTrace(System.err);
                }

            }
        };
        toBitmap(activity, mediaStream, gotFrameListener);
    }

    /**
     * This method captures a frame from the supplied mediastream to a dataurl written to a StringBuilder.
     * @param mediaStream  the source media stream
     * @param quality the quality of the jpeq 0 to 100.
     * @param output a StringBuilder which will be the recipient of the dataurl.
     * @param done a runnable that will be invoked when the dataurl is built.
     * @return The frame capturer. You should keep a reference to the frameCapturer until the done object is invoked.
     */
    public static void toDataUrl(android.app.Activity activity, MediaStream mediaStream, final int quality, final StringBuilder output, final Runnable done) {

        final java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Runnable convertToUrl = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                output.append("data:image/jpeg;base64,");
                output.append(Base64.encodeToString(outputStream.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT));
                try {
                    done.run();
                } catch( Exception e1) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Exception in toDataUrl done callback:" + e1.getMessage());
                    e1.printStackTrace(System.err);
                }
            }
        };
        toOutputStream(activity, mediaStream, quality, outputStream, convertToUrl);
    }
}
```

TextureToRGB

```
import android.opengl.GLES11Ext;
import android.opengl.GLES20;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import org.webrtc.*;
/**
 * Class for converting OES textures RGBA. It should be constructed on a thread with
 * an active EGL context, and only be used from that thread. It is used by the EasyrtcSingleFrameCapturer.
 */
public class TextureToRGB {
    // Vertex coordinates in Normalized Device Coordinates, i.e.
    // (-1, -1) is bottom-left and (1, 1) is top-right.
    private static final FloatBuffer DEVICE_RECTANGLE = GlUtil.createFloatBuffer(new float[] {
            -1.0f, -1.0f, // Bottom left.
            1.0f, -1.0f, // Bottom right.
            -1.0f, 1.0f, // Top left.
            1.0f, 1.0f, // Top right.
    });

    // Texture coordinates - (0, 0) is bottom-left and (1, 1) is top-right.
    private static final FloatBuffer TEXTURE_RECTANGLE = GlUtil.createFloatBuffer(new float[] {
            0.0f, 0.0f, // Bottom left.
            1.0f, 0.0f, // Bottom right.
            0.0f, 1.0f, // Top left.
            1.0f, 1.0f // Top right.
    });


    private static final String VERTEX_SHADER =
            "varying vec2 interp_tc;\n"
                    + "attribute vec4 in_pos;\n"
                    + "attribute vec4 in_tc;\n"
                    + "\n"
                    + "uniform mat4 texMatrix;\n"
                    + "\n"
                    + "void main() {\n"
                    + "    gl_Position = in_pos;\n"
                    + "    interp_tc = (texMatrix * in_tc).xy;\n"
                    + "}\n";

    private static final String FRAGMENT_SHADER =
            "#extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require\n"
                    + "precision mediump float;\n"
                    + "varying vec2 interp_tc;\n"
                    + "\n"
                    + "uniform samplerExternalOES oesTex;\n"
                    + "\n"
                    + "void main() {\n"
                    + "  gl_FragColor = texture2D(oesTex, interp_tc);\n"
                    + "}\n";
    // clang-format on

    private final GlTextureFrameBuffer textureFrameBuffer;
    private final GlShader shader;
    private final int texMatrixLoc;
    private final ThreadUtils.ThreadChecker threadChecker = new ThreadUtils.ThreadChecker();
    private boolean released = false;

    /**
     * This class should be constructed on a thread that has an active EGL context.
     */
    public TextureToRGB() {
        threadChecker.checkIsOnValidThread();
        textureFrameBuffer = new GlTextureFrameBuffer(GLES20.GL_RGBA);
        shader = new GlShader(VERTEX_SHADER, FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        shader.useProgram();
        texMatrixLoc = shader.getUniformLocation("texMatrix");

        GLES20.glUniform1i(shader.getUniformLocation("oesTex"), 0);
        GlUtil.checkNoGLES2Error("Initialize fragment shader uniform values.");
        // Initialize vertex shader attributes.
        shader.setVertexAttribArray("in_pos", 2, DEVICE_RECTANGLE);
        // If the width is not a multiple of 4 pixels, the texture
        // will be scaled up slightly and clipped at the right border.
        shader.setVertexAttribArray("in_tc", 2, TEXTURE_RECTANGLE);
    }

    public void convert(ByteBuffer buf, int width, int height, int srcTextureId,
                        float[] transformMatrix) {
        threadChecker.checkIsOnValidThread();
        if (released) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("TextureToRGB.convert called on released object");
        }

        int size = width * height;
        if (buf.capacity() < size) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("TextureToRGB.convert called with too small buffer");
        }
        // Produce a frame buffer starting at top-left corner, not
        // bottom-left.
        transformMatrix =
                RendererCommon.multiplyMatrices(transformMatrix, RendererCommon.verticalFlipMatrix());

        final int frameBufferWidth = width;
        final int frameBufferHeight =height;
        textureFrameBuffer.setSize(frameBufferWidth, frameBufferHeight);

        // Bind our framebuffer.
        GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, textureFrameBuffer.getFrameBufferId());
        GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, srcTextureId);
        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(texMatrixLoc, 1, false, transformMatrix, 0);
        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

        GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

        GLES20.glReadPixels(
                0, 0, frameBufferWidth, frameBufferHeight, GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buf);

        // Restore normal framebuffer.
        GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

        // Unbind texture. Reportedly needed on some devices to get
        // the texture updated from the camera.
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, 0);
        GlUtil.checkNoGLES2Error("TextureToRGB.convert");
    }

    public void release() {
        threadChecker.checkIsOnValidThread();
        released = true;
        shader.release();
        textureFrameBuffer.release();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think i420Frame will return black screen for few secs. after it will return First frame rendering and in your code renderFrame() method destroy() method will not getting rest of the frames.

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45071308/webrtc-for-android-videorenderergui-take-a-screenshot-in-the-video-call/53045279#53045279

Answer (score 1):

I've just got a solution for your problem, this is how you can get a screen capture of a webrtc call in Android, using SurfaceViewRenderer:

Basically, you must create a custom class implementing `EGLRenderer.FrameListener`, and use it, `<your_surface_view_renderer>.AddFrameListener(EGLRenderer.FrameListener listener, float scale)`.

Then, in the `onFrame` method of your class, you will get a `Bitmap` of each frame. Don't forget to use `removeFrameListener` later.

Comment: Did you implement this? I want to take a screen capture from a video track

Comment: You can add a frame listener to your EGL surface